# Google Maps JQuery Plugin Problem

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Has anyone been able to get this to work?

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-googlemap/

I only seem to get it to work if in debug:true, even then nothing appears like directions.

I am looking for a way either in PHP or jquery to set the address and have the map set it dynamically, as it's one page with the address of many places loaded with php. So the address changes every time.

Comment: After a quick read, I don't see where they are setting the google_maps api key.  Perhaps the google_maps object isn't being loaded because of that?

Comment: No clue, it just makes it easy to load a address without the lat- long
I havent been able to find a alternative to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project is no longer maintained. If I were you I would go with more stable projects such as [jQuery UI and Mobile Google Maps v3 plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/).

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/ none of the examlpes mentioned there work. are you sure the code works??

Comment: All examples I've tested work. Ref: http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui-map-discuss/browse_thread/thread/90282a443ebda926

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. First you need to get your own googlemap key from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html).

Then you need to download the googlemap.js source. I got a copy from [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-googlemap/source/browse/trunk/googlemaps.js?spec=svn3&r=3).

Then you need to include the following references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=PutYourKeyHere"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/googlemaps.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#map").googlemap({ addresses: ["1 ABC ST, NSW 2193 Sydney, Australia"] });
    });
</script>
```

And put a div in

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Note: this plug-in seems to require an id not a class. For example if I define my div to have class="map" instead, $('.map').googlemap() fails with a null reference.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, no controls, it defaults to Australia

Comment: It seems to be particular in the wording of the address. I got it work now. Still no way to get directions though

Comment: If you need more than the simple functionality that googlemaps.gs provides, I suggest you write to the Google Maps API directly. For example, for directions consult http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Directions.